# Loading rdotnet in C# console application fails with an unknown error on macOS

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I have a very basic C# console application on macOS with the code pasted below. When I try to run this code, the call to REngine.GetInstance() fails with the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: This 64-bit process failed to load the library libR.dylib. No further error message from the dynamic library loader
   at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll.ThrowFailedLibraryLoad(String dllFullName, String nativeError)
   at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll.ReportLoadLibError(String dllName, String nativeError)
   at DynamicInterop.UnmanagedDll..ctor(String dllName)
   at RDotNet.REngine..ctor(String id, String dll)
   at RDotNet.REngine.CreateInstance(String id, String dll)
   at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
   at RTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/.../Projects/RTest/RTest/Program.cs:line 14
```

I have made sure that there are no multiple R installations on the system. Also, tried to execute the same code on the M1 machine as well as on Intel-based Mac.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using RDotNet;

namespace RTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var e = REngine.GetInstance();
            e.Initialize();

        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried explicitly specifying R_HOME and R_PATH using REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(rPath: "/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2_1/lib/R/lib", rHome: "/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2_1"); but to no avail.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R can be installed from CRAN (The Comprehensive R Archive Network) for macOS from here https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ or with brew - there are also mixed installations possible.

Also I added the line

```
Console.WriteLine($"is running: {e.IsRunning}");
```

to have an output on the command line in success case to your C# test program.

To get the relevant `R` home directory, you might do the following:

- enter `R` on command line
- enter `R.home(component = "home")`

**CRAN Installation**

With a CRAN installation it would give you `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources`.

Check with `ls /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib` (note the appended path component `lib`) whether there is a `libR.dylib` inside.

Then enter on the command line:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
```

and try to start your .NET app on the command line again. It will presumably show now:

```
Fatal error: R home directory is not defined
```

But we know the home directory from our `R` command above. So next command is:

```
export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
```

Now when you try to start the C# test program on the command line, the message `is running: True` should appear, which means that this time it was successful.

**brew Installation**

The `R` command `R.home(component = "home")` outputs on my machine with brew: `/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.3/lib/R`.

Interestingly on that machine I got initially a different error: `DirectoryNotFoundException:  Directory '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources'`. So I tried by only using

```
export R_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.3/lib/R
```

followed by calling the C# test program on the command line - and it worked.

**Screenshot CRAN Installation**

[image: cran]

**Screenshot brew Installation**

[image: brew]

One notable difference is that I had to explicitly set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the CRAN installation, which was not necessary with the `brew` installation.

`REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables` did not work for me either. So I used the command line to set the environment variables.

But there it was then possible to run it successfully with both installation types, as you can see in the screenshots.

Comment: Thank you so much, Stephan. This really helped. All I needed to do was set those environment variables in IDE and it worked.

Comment: The error, however, is misleading. This only happens if the library is actually found. If the R library is not found, it gives Library not found or something similar. The dlopen() just bails out with no error reported by dlerror() in the former case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that you have two environment variables set.  Either via terminal or via your IDE Environment variable setting mechanism?

From memory the two you need are:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries/:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Spanners. This is not the PATH issue because the error would be different in that case. Also, I tried running the project dynamic-interop (https://github.com/rdotnet/dynamic-interop-dll) directly in an attempt to isolate the error. The error is that dlopen() returns null and then subsequently dlerror() also returns null with no clue of what went wrong